# i cant use the map function TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, reactjs

i just enter to "REACT "  world to do my front-end off my own project and i have problem for 2 day with the function map , i get data from my back-end and i just save the id in the Cuartos array ,  i dont know what its my error , i try it with for loop with console.log in a function out of render   and it work , but work out of the render function how i can resolve it ? i need to get all the cuarto id in the render 
this is my code

```
class FormInterruptor extends React.Component {
    constructor (){
        super();
        const axx={au:[]};
        const Cuartos = [];
        axios.get("http://localhost:5000/API/Cuartos")
        .then(response => {

           const  a=JSON.stringify(response.data);
            console.log(response.data);
            axx.au=response.data;
           const b=JSON.stringify(axx.au.idcuarto);
            console.log("aqui estas" )
           for (let i = 1; i < b.length; i=i+2)
           {
                 Cuartos.push({idcuarto:parseInt((JSON.stringify(axx.au.idcuarto))[i])});
             }
        });


        this.state = {
            IdInterruptor: '',
            IdCuarto: '',
            Pin: '',
            Dimmer: '',
            Cuartos
          };


        }

          onChange(e){
            this.setState({
              [e.target.name]:e.target.value
                     });
          }

      handleSubmit = event => {
            event.preventDefault();

            const Luz = {
              IdInterruptor: this.state.IdInterruptor,
              IdCuarto: this.state.IdCuarto,
              Pin: this.state.Pin,
              Dimmer: this.state.Dimmer

            };

            //AYUDA CON EL LUGAR DODNE SE PONDRA EL INTERRUPTOR 

            let config = {headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"}};
            axios.post('http://localhost:5000/API/Cuarto/1/Luz/add',  Luz , config)
              .then(res => {
                //console.log(res);
                console.log(res.data);
              })
          }
    render(){

        return (

          <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
          <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/Images/Escudo.png'} alt='Escudo' width='400'/>

            <div  className="Formulario"> 
            <h2>
              Formulario Luz
            </h2>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >

                <div id='form'>
               <input  id="form" type="text"placeholder="ID del interruptor" value={this.state.IdInterruptor} name="IdInterruptor" onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />
               </div>
               <div id="separador">


               <select   id="form" name="IdCuarto"   value={this.state.IdCuarto} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} >

               </select>
               </div>

               <div id="separador">

               <input  id="form" type="text" name="Pin"  placeholder="Pin" value={this.state.Pin} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />
               </div>
               <div id="separador">

               <input id="form" type="text" name="Dimmer"  placeholder ="Dimmer" value={this.state.Dimmer} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}/>
               </div>
               <div >
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="button" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                </div>


              </form>
              </div>
              <div> 

               {this.state.Cuartos.map(p => {
                       return  <p  > {p.idcuarto} !</p>}
                            )}


              </div>

          </header>
        </div>

        );

    }
    }

    export default FormInterruptor
```

Update:
i change the code and i change my state in the  componentDidMount and 
this is my data array of Cuartos how i need to use the map function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3r9FX.png)

Comment: Why are you stringifying the response? And what are you getting as the response from the API call that you have in your `constructor`?

Comment: Are you trying to print everything within the `Cuartos`? Or do you only want to print a specific key?

Comment: @wentjun specific key , "idcuartos"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, what you should be doing is to make the HTTP request in the [ComponentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) lifecycle hook instead of the constructor, as the [purpose](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) of the constructor is only for

> - Initializing local state by assigning an object to this.state. Binding
> - event handler methods to an instance.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    IdInterruptor: '',
    IdCuarto: '',
    Pin: '',
    Dimmer: '',
    Cuartos: undefined,
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  let Cuartos;
  axios.get("http://localhost:5000/API/Cuartos")
    .then(response => {

       const  a=JSON.stringify(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
        axx.au=response.data;
       const b=JSON.stringify(axx.au.idcuarto);
        console.log("aqui estas" )
       for (let i = 1; i < b.length; i=i+2) {
         Cuartos.push({idcuarto:parseInt((JSON.stringify(axx.au.idcuarto))[i])});
       }
       this.setState({ Cuartos });
    });

}
```

Then, on your render, you should carry out a check such that you will only carry out `Array.map()` when the request is returned, and that Cuartos is defined, and the `idcuartos` array is not empty.

```
render() {
  const { Cuartos } = this.state;

  return <>
   <div> 
     {
       Cuartos && Cuartos.idcuartos.length && Cuartos.idcuartos.map(p => {
         return . <p>{q}</p>
       })
     }
   </div>
  </>

}
```

Comment: i recive TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: @Gabo4299 try this instead `Cuartos && Cuartos.length && Cuartos.map(...)` I have updated my code

Comment: @Gabo4299 opps, I made a mistake. Thought `Cuartos` was an array. Ok, I have made the changes, such that only `idcuartos` is printed

Comment: i just resolve it , it just &&Cuartos.map (p=>{retunrt <p>{p["idcuartos"]}</p>})

Answer (score 0):

Make your api call in componentDidMount and save your data to state and then manipulate your data before rendering.

```
class FormInterruptor extends React.Component {
    constructor (){
        super();
        this.state = {
            IdInterruptor: '',
            IdCuarto: '',
            Pin: '',
            Dimmer: '',
            Cuartos:[]
          };
        }
         componentDidMount(){
         axios.get("http://localhost:5000/API/Cuartos")
        .then(response => this.setState({Cuartos:res.data}));
         }
          onChange(e){
            this.setState({
              [e.target.name]:e.target.value
                     });
          }

      handleSubmit = event => {
            event.preventDefault();

            const Luz = {
              IdInterruptor: this.state.IdInterruptor,
              IdCuarto: this.state.IdCuarto,
              Pin: this.state.Pin,
              Dimmer: this.state.Dimmer

            };

            //AYUDA CON EL LUGAR DODNE SE PONDRA EL INTERRUPTOR 

            let config = {headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"}};
            axios.post('http://localhost:5000/API/Cuarto/1/Luz/add',  Luz , config)
              .then(res => {
                //console.log(res);
                console.log(res.data);
              })
          }
    render(){

        return (

          <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
          <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/Images/Escudo.png'} alt='Escudo' width='400'/>

            <div  className="Formulario"> 
            <h2>
              Formulario Luz
            </h2>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >

                <div id='form'>
               <input  id="form" type="text"placeholder="ID del interruptor" value={this.state.IdInterruptor} name="IdInterruptor" onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />
               </div>
               <div id="separador">


               <select   id="form" name="IdCuarto"   value={this.state.IdCuarto} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} >

               </select>
               </div>

               <div id="separador">

               <input  id="form" type="text" name="Pin"  placeholder="Pin" value={this.state.Pin} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />
               </div>
               <div id="separador">

               <input id="form" type="text" name="Dimmer"  placeholder ="Dimmer" value={this.state.Dimmer} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}/>
               </div>
               <div >
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="button" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                </div>


              </form>
              </div>
              <div> 

               {this.state.Cuartos.map(p => {
                       return  <p  > {p.idcuarto} !</p>}
                            )}


              </div>

          </header>
        </div>

        );

    }
    }

    export default FormInterruptor
```

Comment: if i did like this i have more arrays in the Cuartos array how i need to use the function map?, i  update the question with a photo of the data in the Cuartos array

Answer (score 0):

You are making a call in the constructor which is not recommended, try doing it in componentDidMount
Javascript is asynchronous so when are making a call using axios it will not wait until the response got back it will continue to render the component, you need to update your component after you got the response
If you still want to render with your existing code, add below line after the for loop inside the axios call back

```
this.setState({"Cuartos": Cuartos})
```